# Almost Schur convexity

Tags: inequality, contest-math

For tuples $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ and $(b_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that $b_1\le b_2\le\cdots\le b_n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i\le \sum_{i=1}^k b_i$. Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^nf(a_i)\le \sum_{i=1}^nf(b_i)$ for an increasing and concave $f:R\rightarrow R$?

**Note:** We have neither $a_1\le a_2\le \cdots \le a_n$ nor $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i= \sum_{i=1}^n b_i$ which are the usual requirements for majorization and Schur convexity.

---

It is true for $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and positive $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: You haven't $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_n$ ?

Comment: Do you intend to exclude functions like $f(x)=-x$ as possible counter-examples?

Comment: @JeanMarie: No. That **is** the point. See my edit.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Good point. I had just added a second condition for it to be increasing before you posted your comment. What do you think?

Comment: “almost Schur” = “on a set of measchure 1”?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: Hahaha, you got the pun. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $m = \min\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ and replacing

\begin{align*}
a_i &\longleftarrow a_i - m, \\ 
b_i &\longleftarrow b_i - m, \\
f(\cdot) &\longleftarrow f(\cdot + m) - f(m),
\end{align*}

it suffices to assume that $a_i \geq 0$, $b_i \geq 0$, and $f(0) = 0$. Then, from the general theory, there exists a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $[0, \infty]$ such that

$$ f(x) = \int_{[0, \infty]} \min\{x, t\} \, \mu(\mathrm{d}t) $$

for all $x \geq 0$. (If $f$ is of $C^2$, then $\mu(\mathrm{d}t) = |f''(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t + f'(\infty) \, \delta_{\infty}(\mathrm{d}t)$.) The upshot of this observation is that it suffices to prove the claim for the function of the form $f(x) = \min\{x, t\}$ for each $ t \in [0, \infty]$.

Let $m \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$ be such that $b_i \leq t$ if and only if $i \leq m$. Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \min\{a_i, t\}
&= \sum_{i=1}^{\min\{k, m\}} \min\{a_i, t\} + \sum_{i \,:\, m < i \leq k} \min\{a_i, t\} \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\min\{k, m\}} a_i + \sum_{i \,:\, m < i \leq k} t \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\min\{k, m\}} b_i + \sum_{i \,:\, m < i \leq k} t \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{k} \min\{b_i, t\}.
\end{align*}

Therefore the claim holds for $f(x) = \min\{x, t\}$ and hence for the general case.

Comment: Nice. This method can be used directly to prove Karamata's inequality, right?

Comment: @Hans, I am not sure about that, since my proof critically hinges on the fact that $f$ is monotone but the [statement of Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) seems not requiring monotonicity.

Comment: We can add a sufficiently large positive or negative linear function to the original function so that the function is monotonic.

Answer (score 4):

The situation can be reduced to that of “regular” majorization and Schur convexity (or [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality)):

Let $(a_1', a_2',  \ldots, a_n')$ be an *increasing rearrangement* of $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, then
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^k a_i' \le \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \le \sum_{i=1}^k b_i
$$
for $1 \le k \le n$. Now increase $a_n'$ so that equality holds for $k=n$, i.e. we set
$$
 a_j'' = \begin{cases}
 a_j' & \text{ for } 1 \le j \le n-1\\
 a_n' + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i' &\text{ for } j = n \, .
\end{cases}
$$
Then $a_1'' \le a_2'' \le \cdots \le a_n''$ and
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^k a_i'' \le \sum_{i=1}^k b_i
$$
for $1 \le k \le n$, with equality for $k=n$.

Now $(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$ majorizes $(a_1'', \ldots, a_n'')$, and it follows that
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i') \le \sum_{i=1}^n f(a_i'')
\le \sum_{i=1}^n f(b_i)
$$
if $f$ is increasing and concave.